# How to pass functions from parent to any children and sub-children using Navigator and WithSecurityScreen in React Native?

Tags: react-native, translation, globalization

I am quite new in React Native and I am trying to understand how function written in a parent Component could be passed (inherited) to any children and sub-children. In particular I am using a library to internationalise my App using:

```
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize'
import i18n from 'i18n-js'
```

But I noticed that I have to implement the `translate(...)` function for each Component of the whole project and this seems to be exaggerated because it requires a lot of work to implement the translation feature (I followed [this tutorial](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-use-react-native-localize-in-react-native-apps-3bb3d510f801)).

Please, note that I have a basic understanding how to pass a function or some data using **this.props**, so I am not asking how **props** works from a parent to a single child. What I am asking is: how to avoid to repeat the code from `//BEGIN ...` to `//END...` (please see WithSecurityScreen file) and to avoid to repeat the implementation of **handleLocalizationChange**, **RNLocalize.addEventListener**, **RNLocalize.removeEventListener** and **translate**.

Please also note that the translation library works, test is provided at following line of WithSecurityScreen:

```
const SecurityScreen = () => <View><Text>{translate('USER_SURNAME')}</Text></View>;
```

But I am not be able to pass **translate(...)** function to each components of the whole project.

The project structure is:

- App.js (wraps SecureApp.js)
- SecureApp.js (wrapped in App.js and runs WithSecurityScreen.js)
- WithSecurityScreen.js (wraps routes to views, e.g. Welcome.js)
- Welcome.js (main view)

**App.js**

```
import { withSecurityScreen } from './src/components/withSecurityScreen'

import App from "./SecureApp.js"

export default withSecurityScreen(App);
```

---

**SecureApp.js**

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Welcome,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false
        }
    },
    UserProfile: {
        screen: CoreApp,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false
        }
    },
    NumPad: {
        screen: NumPad,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: 'PIN Creation',
            headerShown: false
        }
    }, /* , navigationOptions: {headerLeft: () => null} */
    QrScan: {
        screen: QrScan, navigationOptions: {
            header: 'QR Scan',
            headerShown: false
        }
    },
    ...
});

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

---

**WithSecurityScreen.js**

```
// START: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-use-react-native-localize-in-react-native-apps-3bb3d510f801
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize'
import i18n from 'i18n-js'
import memoize from 'lodash.memoize'
const translationGetters = {
    en: () => require('./../../assets/locales/en/en.json'),
    it: () => require('./../../assets/locales/it/it.json')
};

const translate = memoize(
    (key, config) => i18n.t(key, config),
    (key, config) => (config ? key + JSON.stringify(config) : key)
)

const setI18nConfig = () => {
    const fallback = { languageTag: 'en' }
    const { languageTag } =
    RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(Object.keys(translationGetters)) ||
    fallback

    translate.cache.clear()

    i18n.translations = { [languageTag]: translationGetters[languageTag]() }
    i18n.locale = languageTag
}
// END: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-to-use-react-native-localize-in-react-native-apps-3bb3d510f801

const SecurityScreen = () => <View><Text>{translate('USER_SURNAME')}</Text></View>;

const showSecurityScreenFromAppState = appState =>
    ['background', 'inactive'].includes(appState);

const withSecurityScreenIOS = Wrapped => {
    return class WithSecurityScreen extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            setI18nConfig()
        }

        state = {
            showSecurityScreen: showSecurityScreenFromAppState(AppState.currentState)
        };

        componentDidMount() {
            AppState.addEventListener('change', this.onChangeAppState)
            RNLocalize.addEventListener('change', this.handleLocalizationChange)
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.onChangeAppState)
            RNLocalize.removeEventListener('change', this.handleLocalizationChange)
        }

        handleLocalizationChange = () => {
            setI18nConfig()
                .then(() => this.forceUpdate())
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error)
                })
        }

        onChangeAppState = nextAppState => {
            const showSecurityScreen = showSecurityScreenFromAppState(nextAppState);

            this.setState({showSecurityScreen})
        };

        render() {
            return this.state.showSecurityScreen
                ? <SecurityScreen/>
                : <Wrapped {...this.props} />
        }
    }
};

const withSecurityScreenAndroid = Wrapped => Wrapped;

export const withSecurityScreen = Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? withSecurityScreenIOS
    : withSecurityScreenAndroid;
```

---

**Welcome.js**

```
export default class Welcome extends Component {
    let username = 'UserName';
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <LinearGradient colors={globalStyles.colors.gradientGreen} style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={styles.upperView}><Text style={styles.upperViewText}>{this.props.translate('WELCOME_TEXT')}{this.username}</Text>
                    </View>

                </LinearGradient>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I get following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your case you can declare translate function in separate js file locale.js and can declare all your translation logic in that file and export the functions `translate` and `setI18nConfig`

**local.js**

```
  import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize'
    import i18n from 'i18n-js'
    import memoize from 'lodash.memoize'
    const translationGetters = {
        en: () => require('./../../assets/locales/en/en.json'),
        it: () => require('./../../assets/locales/it/it.json')
    };

   export const translate = memoize(
        (key, config) => i18n.t(key, config),
        (key, config) => (config ? key + JSON.stringify(config) : key)
    )

   export const setI18nConfig = () => {
        const fallback = { languageTag: 'en' }
        const { languageTag } =
        RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(Object.keys(translationGetters)) ||
        fallback

        translate.cache.clear()

        i18n.translations = { [languageTag]: translationGetters[languageTag]() }
        i18n.locale = languageTag
    }
```

and import this functions in your components where you want to use this like

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { setI18nConfig, translate } from './locale';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    setI18nConfig(); // This should be called only once through out the app at the time of changing locale. 
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> translate ('key_from_json_to_label') </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

For more details you can [refer this repo](https://github.com/dev-pacific22/react-native-redux-generator) where I have implemented the same.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

i use `import i18n from "i18next"`, for translation.
Here is the config file:

```js
//config/i18n
import i18n from "i18next";
import { reactI18nextModule, initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import translationFR from '../translation/fr/translation.json';
import translationEN from '../translation/en/translation.json';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

let locale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale().substring(0, 2);
if (locale != 'fr') {
  locale = 'en';
}

// the translations
const resources = {
  en: translationEN,
  fr: translationFR,
};

i18n
  .use(reactI18nextModule) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources: resources,
    lng: locale,
    fallbackLng: ['en', 'fr'],
    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

One of the uses is to

```js
import i18n from 'config/i18n'
```

and use translate in file like this

```js
i18n.t('bottomTab:home_tab')
```

You can also wrap component with `withNamespaces` from 'react-i18next', like this:

```js
export default withNamespaces([], {wait: true})(Welcome)
```

and then access translation with:

```js
this.props.t('welcome_message')
```